# VS2010 Extensions - Subscribing to Events

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create an extension for VS2010. I've only just started and one of the things I need to do is to keep track of Project Items.

Upon the initialization of the Package I'd like to subscribe to a set of events.

1) Solution Opened
2) Solution Closed
3) Project Loaded
4) Project Unloaded
5) File Added
6) File Removed

My main problem at the moment is I'm not sure where to start with these Events. I've seen the DTE/Solution/Project/ProjectItem interfaces and I've seen techniques to get them, but none of these have events on in this way.

Does anyone know where I need to be looking to find these events? And how to create an instance to subscribe to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the [EnvDTE.SolutionEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionevents%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which allows what I needed.

Comment: Ian, what did you find for project load/unload? the solutionevents does not have one for these.

Comment: @GasparNagy: In the end I never actually got everything working, due to some odd SDK errors I couldn't get stuff building for ages and gave up on it for a while. I have read there are some quirks about Events and having to keep a reference to them otherwise it doesn't work properly. There's a blog by Scott Hanselmann and I think he does some project event stuff in his extensions - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWorkspaceReloaderAVisualStudioAddInToSaveYourOpenFilesAcrossProjectReloads.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsxue/archive/2008/03/12/tutorial-a-simple-managed-project-system.aspx) post talks about creating a new `Project` template, but probably gives you some ideas about inheriting from `ProjecFactory` and `ProjectNode` classes.

Hope helps!